# looping through a string to check for specific case-matches

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to solve a challenge on pythonchallenge .. it gives you a wall of text with letters of different cases and you try to find the lower case letters surrounded by 3 uppercase letters from each side..
here is my attempt

```
text=open("challenge.txt")
thedata=text.read()

def check(s,c):
    upper='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    lower="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    n=s.index(c)
    if (c in lower) and (s[n-2] in upper) and (s[n+1] in upper) and (s[n-1] in upper) and (s[n+2] in upper) and (s[n-3] in upper) and (s[n+3] in upper):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def solver(s):
    listOfSol=[]
    for c in s:
        try:
            if check(s,c):
                n=s.index(c)
                entry= (s[n-3:n+4])
                if entry not in listOfS:
                    listOfSol.append(entry)
        except KeyError:
            continue
    return listOfSol

print solver(thedata)
```

this is not working and i want to understand why, please don't give me a shortcut answer or try to give me the challenge solution, as i consider myself a python beginner, i just want to know why this doesn't work (always returning an empty list).
thanks in advance

Comment: What if there is more than one of each character in the string? What does `"aBCDaBCD".index("a")` give?

Comment: oh, i didn't think of that, thanks jonsharpe.. i'm going to try approaching this with *enumerate(s)* and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I've solved too much for you, but you can enumerate over the data, then use an add variable within the for loop to skip past letters that match like so:

```
 for index, letter in enumerate(thedata):
      #'add' is a number we're adding to the index that we want to check, so it can be incremented by 7 to skip matching strings
      add = 0
      index2 = index + add

      #use a try-except clause because there is going to be indexerrors checking the end of the string
      try: 
        #if statement goes here
          #add to matches
          add += 7

      except:
        continue
```